# Jquery Datepicker muestra una fecha en un formato que no es

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Tengo una plantilla en blade donde construyo dos datepicker , mi idea es que coja el formato español "dd/mm/YYY" para ello tengo este código

```
    <form id="list_registers_form">

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <input id="dp_start" width="276" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-7 day")); ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <input id="dp_end" width="276" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 day")); ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <button type="button"  id="btn_show_registry_list" class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar</button>
                <div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

En la parte de JavaScript tengo este código para inicializar lo en el formato que quiero.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#dp_start').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        locale: 'es-es',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    });

    $('#dp_end').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        locale: 'es-es',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    });
</script>
```

El funcionamiento que me hace es el siguiente , me muestra la fecha de hoy en el input "23/01/2020", pero si le doy al botón del datepicker me pone la fecha "11/01/2021".  Este es el problema que tengo.

Gracias

Comment: Me podrás decir qué versión de jquery, jquery ui y tal vez bootstrap ocupas para ayudarte?

Comment: jquery uso la 3.2.1 con cdn, bootstrap la 4.1.3

Comment: Ok,pero, entonces cuál sería en realidad el problema? Porque tus datepicker te están dando la fecha como la esperas, es decir, 11/01/2021 en formato dd/mm/YYYY y es confuso saber cuál es el problema.

Comment: El problema esta que si yo le doy "click" al datepicker y selecciono la fecha "3 de enero de 2020" en el "input" me pone "01/03/2020"